# How to change a value in nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, array.prototype.map

Code:

```js
let fruits = [{
    name: 'apple',
    attributes: [{
        type: 'Granny Smith',
        color: 'green',
        isFavorite: true
      },
      {
        type: 'Ambrosia',
        color: 'red',
        isFavorite: true
      }
    ],
    isFavorite: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Pear',
    attributes: [{
        type: 'Asian',
        color: 'brown',
        isFavorite: true
      },
      {
        type: 'White Pear',
        color: 'white',
        isFavorite: false
      }
    ],
    isFavorite: true
  },
]

const fruitChecked = fruits.map(fruit => {
  return { ...fruit,
    isFavorite: true
  }
})

const fruitAttributesChecked = fruitChecked.map(fruit => {


  (fruit.attributes).map(attr => {
    return { ...attr,
      isFavorite: true
    }

  })
})

console.log(fruits)
console.log(fruitChecked)
console.log(fruitAttributesChecked)
```

I am trying to change ALL the isFavorite value to true within each object and the isFavorite value within attributes to true.

However I'm getting something similar to this for [undefined,undefined] for  fruitAttributesChecked

The outcome I desire is below for fruitAttributesChecked

```
fruitAttributesChecked =
[
   {name: 'apple', 
    attributes: [
          {type: 'Granny Smith', color:'green', isFavorite: true},
          {type: 'Ambrosia', color:'red', isFavorite: true}
    ], 
     isFavorite: true
   },
   {name: 'Pear', 
    attributes: [
          {type: 'Asian', color:'brown', isFavorite: true},
          {type: 'White Pear', color:'white', isFavorite: false}
    ], 
     isFavorite: true
   },
]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You're not returning the value of `(fruit.attributes).map`

Comment: Sorry new to this. That makes sense, I have to return ```   (fruit.attributes).map(attr => {
    return { ...attr,
      isFavorite: true
    } ```

Comment: @Robson thats a typo. the desired should have all true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a nested `map()` to return a modified `attributes` array in the object.

```js
let fruits = [{
    name: 'apple',
    attributes: [{
        type: 'Granny Smith',
        color: 'green',
        isFavorite: true
      },
      {
        type: 'Ambrosia',
        color: 'red',
        isFavorite: true
      }
    ],
    isFavorite: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Pear',
    attributes: [{
        type: 'Asian',
        color: 'brown',
        isFavorite: true
      },
      {
        type: 'White Pear',
        color: 'white',
        isFavorite: false
      }
    ],
    isFavorite: true
  },
]

const fruitChecked = fruits.map(fruit => ({ ...fruit,
  isFavorite: true,
  attributes: fruit.attributes.map(attribute => ({ ...attribute,
    isFavorite: true
  }))
}))

console.log(fruitChecked);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const mappedFruits = fruits.map(fruit => {
    return {
        ...fruit,
        isFavorite: true,
        attributes: attributes.map(attribute => {
            return {
                ...attribute,
                isFavorite: true,
            }
        })
    }
})
```